# How to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} E \left[ \left(\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n +\|Z_n\|}} \right)^2 \right]$ where $Z_n$ i.i.d. Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

How to compute the following limit:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} E \left[  \left(\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n +\|Z_n\|^2}} \right)^2 \right]
\end{align}
where $Z_n=[Z_1,...,Z_n]$  is vector of independent and identical Gaussians each with zero mean and with varieance  $\sigma^2$.

At first I tried to use dominated convergence theorem since  $\left(\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n +\|Z_n\|^2}} \right)^2 \le 1$ and I got a limit of zero.  However, I don't think that is correct. What  I didn't do is take into account that $Z_n$ also dependes on $n$.

Comment: Tag (gauge-integral)? What the...

Comment: @Did  I have a typo there is a square missing. The term was suppose to be $\frac{\| Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+\|Z_n\|^2}}$. But Now that you answered the question you don't have to change it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce $$T_n=\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n +\|Z_n\|^2}}$$ and note that $$T_n=\frac{Y_n}{1+ \sqrt{1 +Y_n^2}}$$ where $$Y_n=\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt n}$$ By the law of large numbers, $$Y_n^2=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(Z_n^{(k)})^2\to\sigma^2\ \text{almost surely}$$ hence $$T_n\to\frac{\sigma}{1+\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\ \text{almost surely}$$
Since $0\leqslant T_n\leqslant1$ almost surely, by uniform integrability, this implies that
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E \left[  \left(\frac{ \|Z_n\|}{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n +\|Z_n\|^2}} \right)^2 \right]=\frac{\sigma^2}{(1+\sqrt{1+\sigma^2})^2}$$

Comment: I followed your steps and did for my case.  Is the answer   $\frac{\sigma^2}{1+\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}$, right?